# ASP.net MVC 3 Unobtrusive Client Validations in JQuery Modal Pop up Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, unobtrusive-validation

When I tried to implement ASP.net MVC 3 Unobtrusive Client Validations in the application, the rendered html didn't generate the span tags which are generated by JQuery.

I have only got following rendering html and I used JQuery modal popup as a container for my partial View.

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The City field is required." id="City" name="City" type="text" value="Seattle" />
```

However, when I used Unobtrusive Client validation with out JQuery Modal pop up it works correctly as follows in same application.

```
<div class="editor-field">
  <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The City field is required." id="City" name="City" type="text" value="Seattle" />
  <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="City" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

Is there any thing that I need to implement when I use Unobtrusive Client validations in JQuery Modal Popup?

JQuery Popup Code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#actionPanelDialogs div').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 700,
            appendToBody: true
        });


        $('#actions a').click(function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            var link = $(this);
            var action = link.attr('href');
            var dialogDivId = link.attr('rel');

            var dialogDiv = $('#' + dialogDivId);

            $.get(action, null, function (data) {
                dialogDiv.html(data);

                dialogDiv.dialog('open');                

            });
            return false;
        });
 });
```

Comment: can you post your javascript code for the popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem,

I've used form html to create form element as follows.

```
<form  action="@Url.Action("Create", "Person")" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="contactForm">
```

When I used Html helper it worked correctly.

```
@{using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Person", new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "contactForm" }))
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to manually trigger a parse of any new elements added to the DOM.

```
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#modalPopup");
```

If you are using jQuery UI

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   open: function(event, ui) {
      jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse(ui);
   }
});
```

Comment: from the jQuery Documentation: **Note: The ui object is empty but included for consistency with other events.** so you will probably have to use a selector to find the elements you need to parse

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using bootstrap modals use the following code:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse($(this));
})
```

Thanks to Josh for the guts of it.

Answer (score 0):

Tried all approaches and this is what worked for me:

```
$(".showModal").click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
            $("#modal").load("/Controller/Action?id=" + id, function () {
                $("#modal").modal();
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#modal"));
            })
        });
```